# Orthogonality of conformal blocks?

Tags: conformal-field-theory

[Conformal blocks](https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/0309180.pdf) are solutions to the quadratic casimir differential equation:
[image]
where the last line above is $C_{\Delta,\ell}$ and $\lambda_1=\frac{1}{2}(\Delta+\ell)~~,~~\lambda_2=\frac{1}{2}(\Delta-\ell)$, and where all the $\Delta_i,\ell$ are parameters.

While the differential operator $(2.3)$ does not depend on $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$ the equation $(2.2)$ can produce solutions for any values of these parameters. My question is:

> Are the different solutions with different parameters $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$ orthogonal to each other? And if yes, what is the explicit inner product? (At least in $d=2$?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a notion of orthogonality among conformal blocks with different $\Delta$ and $\ell$.

There is a nice explanation in the introduction of this recent paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.03816.
Or alternatively, you can go back to the original literature from the 1970's starting with https://doi.org/10.1007/BFb0009678.

Without going into too much details, the idea is to define "conformal partial waves", which are a linear combinations of the conformal block $G_\Delta^{(\ell)}$ and its "shadow block" $G_{d-\Delta}^{(\ell)}$ (that is the block with $\Delta$ replaced by $d - \Delta$, where $d$ is the spacetime dimension).

The conformal partial waves evaluated at the unphysical scaling dimension $\Delta = d/2 + i r$ (with $r > 0$) are orthogonal to each other and the inner product is given by eq. (1.3) of https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.03816.